# cannot allocate memory in static TLS block

Tags: java

I have written tests for a java code. I am trying to run the tests but it fails with an error saying:

```
java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block.
```

I have tried a lot of google search. But did not get much from there. Does anyone know the reasons for this error and the possible resolutions? Thanks

Comment: What does your code look like?

Answer (score 2):

TLS is ThreadLocalStorage and it seems you are trying to stuff too much into a ThreadLocal object. The VM preallocates memory for each thread for this. AFAIK you cannot adjust this yourself, the only flag that I know of that adjusts a threads memory consumption is the '-XX:ThreadStackSize=' and there are no guarantees that this will fix any of your problems.
Best I can offer is rewrite your code.